# Using finish to pass Array intent data

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, bundle, start-activity

I have this method that passes an array to a different activity. anotherrow is an arrayList

```
  private fun returnToPreviousActivityWithTheData() {
    // intialize Bundle 
    val b = Bundle()
    b.putSerializable("questions", anotherRow as Serializable?)
    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtras(b)
    startActivity(i)
    finish()
}
```

And this is how am receiving the intent:

```
        val b = activity?.getIntent()?.extras
        if (b?.getSerializable("questions") as ArrayList<bring> != null) {
            returnedArray = (b!!.getSerializable("questions") as ArrayList<bring>?)!!
        }
```

I need help on how i can send and receive the data using finish method  alone (finishing the current activity without calling startactivity) as i have other layout selections in the mainactivity that get recreated with startactivity.

Comment: What is your problem exactly or what do you want??

Comment: @ milad salimi   i need t o return to activity A without calling startactivity, just using finish. startactivity creates a new intent

Comment: Do you want to send data without start activity?

Comment: @milad salimi It is possible with startActivityForResult.